# How can I get a file that might be under the src folder and might be in the jar?

Tags: java

I have a resource file I need to read from my code. So when I'm developing it's under the src folder (and copied under the classes folder). When we're in production it's in the jar file.

How can I set an absolutely qualified path to the file that works for all cases?

Update: Trying the following but it doesn't always work

```
is = getResourceStream(RESOURCE_PATH + afmFile + ".afm", resourceAnchor.getClass().getClassLoader());
if(is==null){
    is = getResourceStream("src/"+RESOURCE_PATH + afmFile + ".afm", resourceAnchor.getClass().getClassLoader());
}
```

Comment: It won't be under the src folder when you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Class.getResource()` or `Class.getResourceAsStream()` for exactly this purpose.

Comment: An example loading images as resources is in _The Java™ Tutorials_ section [Retrieving Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html)

Comment: @Vampire - We have that. But it isn't always working. Please look at the update.

Comment: What is `getResourceStream()`? If you use `getResourceAsStream()` correctly, it works like expected. If it doesn't work like expected you are most probably using it wrongly. ;-)